# Adding or subtracting mean absolute error

Tags: units, measurements

In an experiment to find the length of a rod, n observations were made. ${a_1,\;a_2,\;.\;.\;.\;a_n}$. The mean (${a_{mean}}$) of those observations will give a value very close to the true length of the rod. After calculating ${a_{mean}}$, we find the mean absolute error (${\pm \Delta a_{mean}}$). The '${\pm}$' sign indicates that we must add ${\Delta a_{mean}}$ and subtract ${\Delta a_{mean}}$. To which value should we add ${\Delta a_{mean}}$? From which value should we subtract ${\Delta a_{mean}}$? I think it is not required to do the addition or subtraction to ${a_{mean}}$ because, ${a_{mean}}$ is already very close to the true length. Please give your opinion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The mean (${a_{\rm mean}}$) of those observations will give a value (very) close to the true length of the rod

and the error (${\pm \Delta a_{\rm mean}}$) will give you an indication of how close your mean value might be to the actual length of the rod.

At the start of an experiment you do not know the true length of the rod.

You take some measurements and from those readings you find a mean of the measurements (${a_{\rm mean}}$) and a measure of the spread of the measurements (${\pm \Delta a_{\rm mean}}$).

You can then infer that there is a probability that the actual length of the rod is within the range $a_{\rm mean}\pm \Delta a_{\rm mean}$.
Statistically analysis can be used to estimate the value of that probability.